# How to fix warning

Tags: function, remix

from solidity:
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to view
--> contracts/2B2T_UK.sol:20:5:
|
20 |     function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
|     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

---

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
    return balances[owner];
}

function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[msg.sender] -= value;
   emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[from] -= value;
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;   
}

function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;   
}
```

}

Like to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

> Function state mutability can be restricted to view

When your function doesn't change any state (doesn't store to storage, doesn't emit events), you can mark it as a `view` function.

View function signalizes that it doesn't change any state and that it's safe for offchain apps to invoke this function using a free (but read-only) call instead of using a transaction (that costs gas fees but can change state).

```
function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
    return balances[owner];
}
```